# Web page not found .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am new to working with asp.net core 2.1, I have added few Razor Views but on publishing application to azure, I am unable to access those pages. I get "no web page was found" error.

[image]

Here is My Solution explorer

[image]

I guess there is an issue with StartUp.cs wherein, I need to route things but I didn't find proper documentation since I am using .net core 2.1.

Comment: Show us the `HomeController`, do you have a `customform` action method in there?

Comment: @DavidG :  Oh yes. I forgot to add action method in Home Controller, adding that the issue is solved. Thanks a lot  :)